# Laravel: Include a Blade with dynamic value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to include a Blade into my view:

The name of the view which I want to include is:

1.blade.php

When I call it with:

```
@include('1')
```

then everything is working. When I try to load "1" out of the Database with

```
@include(' {{ $cats->id }}')
```

where the id = 1 then I get the error message:

throw new InvalidArgumentException("View [{$name}] not found.");

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Kind Regards,

Stefan

Comment: Templating `{{ }}` is not needed when `@include` is also a PHP command. Change it to `@include(''.$cats->id)`

Comment: Also, giving a name as `1` to a blade file is `not` a good way to name blade files. It needs to be more descriptive.

Comment: Dear Vivek, thank you for your advice and help. It works like a charm :-) Kind Regards, Stefan

Comment: @vivek_23 I guess he is using the `id` of a model to relate to the view. But I agree with you, it seems a bit weird. If it is dynamic templates that are loaded here, they should probably be stored elsewhere (e.g. db).

Comment: @Namoshek Yes, I agree with you. The OP can also go with conditional statements if at all it needs to be loaded dynamically based on certain criteria.